# Module Cronjob not running on Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, configuration, cron

i am trying to run a custom cronjob, however it doesn't seem to do anything. cron.php is running (is on crontab and writes to log after modification).

The `cron_schedule` table has entries, but doesn't list the cronjob of my module.
I also cleared the cache.

Here is the part of my xml dealing with the cronjob:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <vendor_foobar>
            <class>Vendor_FooBar_Model</class>
        </vendor_foobar>
    </models>

    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <vendor_foobar>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>vendor_foobar/observer::checkFoo</model>
                </run>
            </vendor_foobar>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</global>
```

There is a path Vendor/FooBar/Model in app/local and it has a file called `Observer.php` with a class called `Vendor_FooBar_Model_Observer`:

```
class Vendor_FooBar_Model_Observer {
   public function checkFoo(){
       # ...
   }
}
```

I tried various things to make the effect of checkFoo visible: Writing to logs, throwing an exception, even sending an email. But it doesn't seem to be called at all, which fits the observation, that it isn't listed in `cron_schedule`.

Maybe there is something wrong with my code, maybe there is some requirement i am missing. But if not: Where in the core can i put debugging points to show what is going wrong? The mechanism indicated in cron.php seems a bit cryptic :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<crontab>` node should not be inside the `<global>` node.

Your config.xml should look as follows.

```
<global>
    <models>
        <vendor_foobar>
            <class>Vendor_FooBar_Model</class>
        </vendor_foobar>
    </models>
</global>
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <vendor_foobar>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>vendor_foobar/observer::checkFoo</model>
            </run>
        </vendor_foobar>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```